# App Customization Specialist issue- Build Volunteer Tracker app reports

Tags: reporting, custom-reports

I'm getting error as :
Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
The 'My Upcoming Confirmed Shifts' component is using the incorrect source report.

I have used My Upcoming Shifts report in the dashboard component with the below filters, not able to understand what is wrong here:

[image]

Comment: Sorry to say, but as this is clearly a [Superbadge question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2243/trailhead-where-do-we-draw-the-line), I suggest to close it.

Comment: I had just asked for guidance, anyways thanks, 
it was just an issue of dashboard refresh